# return all but the excluded fields from mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

i have created a collection in mongodb named 'Scores' and the documents stored in the collection is of following type:

```
    {
"_id": "5aa0128de579e00738c3e108",
"id": "LszN4n0TdsCsoHi8AAAA",
"score": 14
}
{
"_id": "5aa007454b20c52ba488a5f4",
"id": "WVLRujy7djsxarrxAAAB",
"score": 8
},
{
"_id": "5aa007484b20c52ba488a5f5",
"id": "cml_M0-E_UqjslzvAAAA",
"score": 5
}
```

But i want to retrieve only the score field from all the documents and exclude the _id and id fields but i am unable to do so even when i am setting _id:0, id:0. After the find query the server is returning all the fields from all the documents

```
   db.collection('Scores').find({},{"id":0}).toArray().then((docs)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2));
    },(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: If you are using version 3.0 or higher of the mongodb driver, try `db.collection('Scores').find({},{ projection: { _id: 0 } })`. See the documentation for more info: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your code like this:

```
db.collection('Scores').find({}, {
        score: 1,
        _id: 0
    })
    .then((docs) => {
            if (docs) {
                console.log(docs));
        } else {
            console.log('There is no data in DB');
        }

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

It gives you folllowing output:

```
[
   {
       "score" : 14
   },
   {
       "score" : 8
   },
   {
       "score" : 5
   }
]
```

Here you don't need to pass `.toArray()` because `find()` always give response in `array` where `findOne()` gives response in `Object`.